# When I save my HTML file in WebStorm, it reloads from disk with file watcher

Tags: webstorm

When I save my html file in WebStorm, all changes are revert (as if I would press Ctrl + Alt + Y). But it happens only if any file watcher is active. I use standard SCSS file watcher.

I tried to change settings (files to refresh, arguments, auto-save) but it changed nothing.

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

UPDATE: It also works in other JetBrains IDEs.

UPDATE 2:
I invalidated caches, created other project, created other scss file watcher, added $ProjectFileDir$ to "outputs paths to refresh" and the issue was solved!
It's so strange, even using other IDE didn't help, but creating other project did.

Comment: What is your IDE version? Will it show the correct new content after you manually use `File | Reload All from Disk`?

Comment: Version 2022.3. No.

Comment: Odd. Do you happen to have your old project settings (`.idea` subfolder content) to compare the settings / find out what could be wrong?

Comment: Yes. I compared it, the problem was simple: file watcher arguments can't contains "..". But after adding it in my new project, it got broken again! And again, nothing but creating new project helped. (Even removing .idea from my project directory)

Comment: Show the bad one (the screenshot of File Watcher) and why do you need them there. There can be another way of achieving the same.

Comment: Yes, i used it because when i created this project i didn't know about $ProjectFileDir$. So, issue solved. But anyways i can't understand why it breaks projects.

Comment: If you are sure that it is what is causing the File Watcher to stop working/makes him misbehave then please make a ticket at WebStorm Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB with your findings. A code / settings before and after are much appreciated (so there will be no guesses what to use and where in order to reproduce it).